# How to deploy a Google Run with GPU enabled?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-anthos

I have tried to create a Google Run for Anthos but even if I create clusters I have always a message that say You don't have any clusters with Cloud Run for Anthos enabled.
Create an Anthos GKE cluster to start.

How do you do that?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what problem you are solving. Add more details, show the steps, error messages, configuration files, etc. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Do you have issues with GPUs or Cloud Run for Anthos. Not sure to understand your issue.

Comment: I have added a screenshot. There is somewhere they ask me to create new anthos cluster but i have already some registred. If i add some, i do not see it in this section

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot provided, here is a reference [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/install) that you can use to install the Cloud Run for Anthos service. In the documentation, there is a Google Cloud install prerequisites.

Adding here a [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/setup) as reference on how to set up the Cloud Run for Anthos.

Lastly is on how to [Adding a node pool with GPUs to your GKE cluster](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/configuring/compute-power-gpu#gpu-node-pool).